# Problem with Excel Userform resolution - Text and image enlargement

Tags: excel, vba, userform, resolution

I'm having a problem in an Excel file with 6 userforms where it seems that the resolution of 5 of them changed - all userforms have a similar header, so its easy to see the difference between them.

The problem at the 5 userforms is a clear enlargement of the text in every OptionButton, Label or CommandButton (its really strange one of them still being OK)

What I've relaize so far:

. Compared the zoom of every userform - all 6 at 100%

. Compared the font between userforms - similar size letters are displayed differently between the only OK userform and the other 5

. The same image present in every userform (Height and Width = 48) is clearly a square in the OK userform and a rectangle in the other 5 (something like Height =66 and Width = 48)

. Changed the resolution of the PC to 125%, but the problem remained

. Tried every type of projection between screens (mirrored between laptop and monitor, only laptop, expandable, etc)

Example:

[Print of nOK Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEARY.png)

[Print of OK Userform from a back-up file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59lPW.png)

Would really appreciate your help in this subject!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.